# How to fetch records that specfic strings in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to fetch record that a columun has specfic strings. My Laravel framework is 5.7.28

Here is my DB. Take a look 'image' columun.

For example. I would like to fetch record that 'images' name include '01' strings.
I give name all image data those front 2 letters are numbers such as  '01', '02', '03' ....

Could you please teach me how to write controller code?

**Here is my current controller**

```
public function index2()
    {            
        $images = ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(image), image'))->paginate(10);
        return view('image-gallery2',compact('images'));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `like` operator combined with `%` wildcards. This statement means something similar to 01 where anything can come after.

```
ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(image), image'))
    ->where('image', 'like', '01%')
    ->paginate(10)
```

Alternatively you can utilize the `LEFT` function call in MySql, that takes n characters from the left of a string.

```
->where(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '01')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a question. How about image name like this '03-photo-0103-2020' ? I made rule to giving name First two letter is key. so I would like to check frist 2 letter .

Comment: Didnt think of that edgecase, update my answer with an alternative solution. I would assume the LEFT call would have performance issues on big tables.

Comment: Dear @mrhn Thank you very much.I've been trying but I couldn't get record . Here is my current code $images = ImageGallery::where(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '01');  and No error message.just white empty page show up. Do you have any idea of this?

Comment: To debug it, you can debug it with ->select(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)')) and dd() the result

Comment: Thank you very much! now I got records . I use $images = ImageGallery::where(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '02')->get(); Thank you so much for helping. I studied a lot. I apreciate!!!